# Android Application Crashes Custom Listview while running getView part

Tags: java, android

I am creating a custom adapter using data from the web.
Below is what I've been working on. The logcat says it's having problem at

```
view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_each, null);
```

in the getView part. This is line 49 of ArticleListAdapter, as indicated in the error line below logcat.

The full logcat around the error is like below. (Is there anyway I can get a more detailed error log?)
* I updated the log below! (please let me know if this is still not the right log to provide.)

```
04-17 22:57:53.408 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=102
04-17 22:57:53.408 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=85
04-17 22:57:53.419 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 D/ViewRootImpl@64962f[Toast]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
04-17 22:57:53.425 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=98
04-17 22:57:53.427 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 D/ViewRootImpl@64962f[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{7f0743c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
04-17 22:57:53.430 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403.ArticleListAdapter.getView(ArticleListAdapter.java:49)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3238)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2147)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:767)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:833)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1900)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:3008)
04-17 22:57:53.438 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.439 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
04-17 22:57:53.440 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:884)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
04-17 22:57:53.441 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
04-17 22:57:53.442 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2375)
04-17 22:57:53.442 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1526)
04-17 22:57:53.442 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7102)
04-17 22:57:53.442 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
04-17 22:57:53.442 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
04-17 22:57:53.442 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
04-17 22:57:53.443 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
04-17 22:57:53.445 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-17 22:57:53.451 22401-22401/org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403, PID: 22401
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403.ArticleListAdapter.getView(ArticleListAdapter.java:55)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3238)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2147)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:767)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:833)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1900)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:3008)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:884)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2375)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1526)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7102)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

I've tried many different ways but still can't figure out what has gone wrong. I would be grateful for any suggestion and comment! Thank you!

Below is the custom adapter I am creating,

```
package org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

class ArticleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> articleList;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ArticleListAdapter (Context context,  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> articleList) {
        super();
        this.articleList = articleList;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
        if(articleList==null)
            return 0;
        else
            return articleList.size();
    }

    @Override public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        if(null==articleList) return null;
        else
            return articleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_each, null);
        TextView titleView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        HashMap<String, String> eacharticle = articleList.get(position);

        if(eacharticle != null ) {
            String title = eacharticle.get("title");
            titleView.setText(title);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

and below is ArticleList activity.

```
package org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class ArticleList extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent;
    String articlelist;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> articleList;
    ListView ArticleListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.article_list);
        intent = getIntent();
        articlelist = intent.getStringExtra("articlelist");

        articleList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArticleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.articlelistbox);
        getArticleList(articlelist);
    }

    public void getArticleList(String url) {
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uri = "http://www.critiquers.org/android/articlelist.php?articlelist="+params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                try {

                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String no = c.getString("no");
                        String url = c.getString("url");
                        String title = c.getString("title");
                        String date_mktime = c.getString("date_mktime");
                        String media = c.getString("media");
                        String media_no = c.getString("media_no");
                        String author = c.getString("author");
                        String author_no = c.getString("author_no");
                        String facebook_no= c.getString("facebook_no");
                        String rep_image= c.getString("rep_image");

                        HashMap<String, String> addarticle = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        addarticle.put("no", "no");
                        addarticle.put("url", "url");
                        addarticle.put("title", "title");
                        addarticle.put("media", "media");
                        addarticle.put("media_no", "media_no");
                        addarticle.put("author", "author");
                        addarticle.put("author_no", "author_no");
                        addarticle.put("date_mktime", "date_mktime");
                        addarticle.put("facebook_no", "facebook_no");
                        addarticle.put("rep_image", "rep_image");
                        articleList.add(addarticle);
                    }

                    Integer size = articleList.size();
                    String sizeTxt = size.toString();
                    Toast.makeText (ArticleList.this, sizeTxt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //아래에 정의될 커스텀어댑터 클래스로 어댑터를 설졍한다
                    ArticleListAdapter articleadapter = new ArticleListAdapter(
                            ArticleList.this,
                            articleList
                    );

                    ArticleListView.setAdapter(articleadapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end try catch
            }//end onPostExecute
        }//end GetDataJSON
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute(url);
    }//end getArticleList


    public void xClicked(View v){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: *it's having problem* is not enough, we need the crash stack trace ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited and added the logcat around the error. I'd deeply appreciate if you could take a look!

Comment: the above is *not* the error stacktrace. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: This is not the stacktrace bit that contains your code. You need to share the bits that show lines in your code. Where we can see the type of Exception and cause. Without that, we can't narrow down on the error.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I've just updated the log once again. I would be very grateful if you could take a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_each,parent,false);//the good way
    TextView titleView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);

    HashMap<String, String> eacharticle = articleList.get(position);

    if(eacharticle != null ) {
        String title = eacharticle.get("title");
        titleView.setText(title);
    }
    return view;
}
```

learn more [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

for this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at org.androidtown.slidingexercise20180403.ArticleListAdapter.getView(ArticleListAdapter.java:55)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3238)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2147)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:767)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:833)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1900)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:3008)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:884)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2375)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1526)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7102)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: Could you provide more explanation on how this is a solution, and how it is related to the error?

Comment: [look at this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. And the link helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this on getView method

```
view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_each, null);
```

to

```
 view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_each, parent, false);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Can you explain why this would solve an error, and which error you're solving ? IMO there's a good chance that 'parent.getContext()' would return the same as just using 'context' so I believe these 2 lines to be equivalent in terms of errors...